# The onclick is not working on first click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on one JavaScript project, where I need to toggle between Celsius and Fahrenheit.
The HTML is here

```
<button onclick="toggleCF();" id="toggleCF" class="button">Toggle C/F</button>
```

And here is the JavaScript Function

```
this.toggleCF = function() {
    console.log('click');
    var fahrenheit = document.getElementById('toggleFahrenheit');
    var celsius = document.getElementById('toggleCelsius');

    if (fahrenheit.style.display === 'none') {
        fahrenheit.style.display = 'block';
        celsius.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        fahrenheit.style.display = 'none';
        celsius.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

The CSS I used is given

```
.temperature-celsius {

}
.temperature-fahrenheit {
    display: none;
}
```

If you want to check this application live here is the link

[Please click on this link to see app in running form](https://codepen.io/ziaullahzia/pen/GvoZRZ?editors=1000)

If you visit the above link and check, you will find that on first click the toggle didn't work. But when you click the second time then it starts working normally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not work because this `if (fahrenheit.style.display === 'none')` will return NULL as there is no inline style on the element. this method won't "look" at CSS, it only works for inline styles. You could try this:

```
var element = document.getElementById('toggleFahrenheit'),
    style = window.getComputedStyle(element),
    top = style.getPropertyValue('top');
```

to check the CSS properties in pure JS or you could use JQuery which would solve it in one line of code.

Answer (score 5):

When the app is first loaded, both the `toggleFahrenheit` and `toggleCelsius` divs have no `style` attribute.  They are getting display rules from the CSS, true, but they have no `style` on themselves.

So think about what your code sees, then.  `fahrenheit.style.display` is null because that block doesn't have the `style` attribute yet.  Therefore, `fahrenheit.style.display === 'none'` evaluates to false.  As a result, the `else` block is executed and you end up displaying Celsius.  Unfortunately, this is the default block which is shown, so the first click doesn't do anything.

The second click works because after the code executes once, now both div blocks have a `style` attribute.

To fix this, you should either put default style attributes onto the div tags or flip the logic in the code so you check on the Celsius block first, since that's the default display.

Personally, I would use classes to toggle display behaviour instead.

```js
function toggle() {
  var fahrenheit = document.getElementById("fahrenheit");
  var celsius = document.getElementById("celsius");
  fahrenheit.classList.toggle('hide');
  celsius.classList.toggle('hide');
}
```

```css
.hide { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="fahrenheit" class="hide">-40 F</div>
<div id="celsius">-40 C</div>
<button onclick="toggle()">Toggle</button>
```

And yes, I use -40 degrees in the example because I'm lazy and I happen to know this is the same temperature in both systems (:

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately, I am not clear. Do I need changes in if statement logic?

Comment: Essentially, if you are going to use state on the html to encode which block is displayed, then it should be evident from the html which block is the default.  If you put `style="display: none;"` on the fahrenheit block and `style="display: block;"` on the celsius block, you achieve this and your code as written will work.

Answer (score 0):

This often happen most of the time on your css content not being been loaded up fully i have my issue solved with the following code:

```
function yourFunction() {
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
       // you works start here
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to use the EventListener .
I had the same problem with the onclick but when using :

```js
const myEl = document.getElementById('myBtn');
myEl.addEventListener('click', function () {

//Your code here

});
```

It works on first click!